# Sublime Text Blade Highlighter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, sublimetext3, laravel-blade, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Medalink's Blade Highlighter for Sublime Text 3 (https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade)

I encountered, that the forelse directive isn't highlighted correctly, as you can see in this picture
[image: @forelse is not being highlighted correctly]

Is this my computer's fault?

Comment: Sounds like you might have more luck here: https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade/issues

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. What is it supposed to look like? If you have a problem with a plugin, it may be easier to open an issue with the developer.